# Redux mapDispacthToProps - prop not invoked when called from unload event

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a requirement to call an API when unload event is fired [browser/tab close.] I want to dispacth an action which would take care of calling the API. However the action is not invoked it seems.

```
unload(e) {
    if (shouldCallApi()) {
      this.props.submit();
    }
  }
export const handleSubmit = dispatch => () => {
  dispatch(submitApp());
  return true;
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  submit:  handleSubmit(dispatch),
});
```

handleSubmit method is not called at all

Answer (score 1):

Problem comes from your initialization of `submit` in `mapDispatchToProps`.

`submit: handleSubmit(dispatch),` actually initialize submit with **the returned value of handleSubmit** which is not defined as I guess it is not what you are trying to do.

You need to set submit with a **function object** to be able to call it as a function, by simply **refering to its name**.

```
unload(e) {
    if (shouldCallApi()) {
      this.props.submit(dispatch);
    }
  }
export const handleSubmit = dispatch => () => {
  dispatch(submitApp());
  return true;
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  submit: handleSubmit,
});
```

This mean, you have to call `this.props.submit(dispatch);` with **dispatch as parameter** and so manage to have it **shared in you unload function**.